# VUE and Pagination : pag.component loose values after pager is changed/clicked

Tags: javascript, pagination, vue.js, vuejs2

I am implementing a pager in my VUE app, and at first load, everything works fine.. The parameters needed for the pager-component is sat correctly, and the pager displays as it should..

Problem is.. when i *navigate* (use/click) the pager, all props are sat to Undefined and presents me one evil :

```
[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "currentPage". Expected Number, got Undefined.
```

When i use the VUE debugger in Chrome i notice :

[image]

**My thoughts :**

1. Must be something wrong with passing prop values to the pager
2. Pager is instancified before the values are sat ?

**Snippet for Home.VUE component :**

```js
import * as types from '../store/mutationtypes'
import { mapGetters, mapActions } from 'vuex'
import Pagination from './Pagination.vue'
import Modal from './Modal.vue'

var moment = require('moment')

export default {
    name: 'Home',
    data() {
        return {
            FiltersVisible: false,
            orderList: {
                currentPage: 1,
                totalPages: this.$store.state.ordersCount / 10,
                // totalPages:5,
                itemsPerPage: 10
            },
            showModal: false,
            searchString: ''
        }
    },
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters(['orders', 'ordersCount']),
        totalPages() {
            return this.ordersCount / 10
        }
        // ...mapGetters(['orders'])
    },

    methods: {
        ...mapActions(['getOrders']),
        init() {
            var queryParams = null;
            this.getOrders(queryParams)
        },
        doSearch: function() {
            var queryParams = {
                searchString: this.searchString
            }
            this.getOrders(queryParams)
        },
        viewOrder: function(order) {
            this.$router.push('/vieworder/' + order._source.orderid)
        },
        viewAppInfo: function(order) {
            this.$router.push('/viewappinfo/' + order._source.mobileinstanceid)
        },
        humanDate: function(dateToFormat) {
            return moment(dateToFormat).format("DD.MM.YYYY [kl: ] hh:mm")
        },
        orderListChanged(pageNum) {
            this.orderList.currentPage = pageNum;
            var queryParams = {
                skip: (pageNum * this.orderList.itemsPerPage) - this.orderList.itemsPerPage,
                take: this.orderList.itemsPerPage
            };
            this.orderList = this.getOrders(queryParams)
        },
        toggleModal: function(actionName, orderItem) {
            var modalParams = {
                modalComponent: actionName,
                selectedOrderItem: orderItem,
                userProfileId: null
            }
            this.$store.dispatch('switchModalComponent', {
                modalParams: modalParams
            })
            this.showModal = true;
        },
    },
    watch: {
        'ordersCount': function(val) {
            if (val) {
                this.orderList.totalPages = val / 10
            }
        },
        route: function() {
            this.init()
            console.log("Orderscount er = " + ordersCount)
            console.log(this)
        }
    },
    created() {
        this.init()
    },
    components: {
        'modal': Modal,
        'Pagination': Pagination
    }
}
```

```html
<template>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      .....Order data looped through and presented here....

    <h1>This is page {{ orderList.currentPage }}</h1>

    <pagination :current-page="orderList.currentPage" :total- pages="orderList.totalPages" :items-per-page="orderList.itemsPerPage" @page-changed="orderListChanged">
    </pagination>


    </div>
</template>
```

**Snippet for Pagination.VUE**

```js
import Util from './services/Util'

export default {
  props: {
    currentPage: {
      type: Number,
      required: true
    },
    totalPages: Number,
    itemsPerPage: Number,
    totalItems: Number,
    visiblePages: {
      type: Number,
      default: 5,
      coerce: (val) => parseInt(val)
    }
  },

  methods: {
    activePage(pageNum) {
      return this.currentPage === pageNum ? 'active' : ''
    },
    pageChanged(pageNum) {
      this.$emit('page-changed', pageNum)
    }
  },

  computed: {
    lastPage() {
      if (this.totalPages) {
        return this.totalPages
      } else {
        return this.totalItems % this.itemsPerPage === 0 ?
          this.totalItems / this.itemsPerPage :
          Math.floor(this.totalItems / this.itemsPerPage) + 1
      }
    },
    paginationRange() {
      let start = this.currentPage - this.visiblePages / 2 <= 0 ?
        1 : this.currentPage + this.visiblePages / 2 > this.lastPage ?
        Util.lowerBound(this.lastPage - this.visiblePages + 1, 1) :
        Math.ceil(this.currentPage - this.visiblePages / 2)
      let range = []
      for (let i = 0; i < this.visiblePages && i < this.lastPage; i++) {
        range.push(start + i)
      }
      return range
    }
  }

}

Util.JS

lowerBound (num, limit) {
      return num >= limit ? num : limit
    }
```

```html
<template>
    <ul class="pagination">
        <li>
            <a href="#" @click.prevent="pageChanged(1)" aria-label="Previous">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li v-for="n in paginationRange" :class="activePage(n)">
            <a href="#" @click.prevent="pageChanged(n)">{{ n }}</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" @click.prevent="pageChanged(lastPage)" aria-label="Next">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</template>
```

**Updated 05.10 - Order before paging :** 
[image]

**Updated 05.10 - Order after paging**
[image]

Comment: can you show the content for `getOrders` action, or provide the consol.log of it's output after a change? My guess is something sets may be breaking there.

Comment: @Daniel : Updated the question with Order result before and after paging is used (clicked)..

Comment: See especially after paging : OrderList is "Promise" ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is definitely in the `getOrders` action. without seeing it, I cannot pinpoint what it is, but based on the screenshot I feel like I can take a good guess. I'm assuming you're using an async call to an api every time you hit next page, if not, it's a whole lot easier.

`getOrders` returns a promise. that is most likely because it is an asynchronous function using axios/fetch or some other lib to do remote call. The way vuex works is that the actions are asynchronous and mutations are synchronous. If you call

```
this.orderList = this.getOrders(queryParams)
```

you are are assigning the asynch function as the value, which is guaranteed to return a promise.

what you need to do is split the functionality into a getter and an actions

you call the action to get new data from remote server (assuming that's what you're using)
as part of the callback/promise response, you mutate the data into the store

you also make a getter (`orderList`) available that you can access from your component, and use that instead of defining `orderList` in the component

when a user hits prev/next or any page, you...

- call action - updateList(queryParams)

  - clear the orderList in the store (`store.orders = []`) as part of the action
  - make an api call
  - on success, update data
- update view to display a loading data animation
- once the data is updated, reactivity will kick in and the `orderList` will repopulate

  - using a watch or a `orderList > 0`, remove the loading animation